# Internal server error when returning an object with X-Ray dependency

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, aws-xray

I am trying to update my current functions from Node 6.10 to Node 8.10. In this migrating, I would like to return objects instead of calling the lambda callback. 
For example, the code below works correctly.

```
module.exports.handler = async () => {
  console.info('my lambda function');
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: '{}',
  };
};
```

The issue occurs when the AWS X Ray dependency is added. For example, the code below fails with 502 "Internal Server Error".

```
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk-core');

module.exports.handler = async () => {
  console.info('my lambda function');
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: '{}',
  };
};
```

Did anyone had this issue before?

Comment: That's already reported upstream, including a workaround: https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/issues/27